# How to use a geolocation field from a flag to calculate proximity

Tags: 7, flags, location

I'm using the Flag module for the notifications system on my site. One of the notifications is supposed to be "Notify me when a new node is created near my location".

I added two fields to a flag: a geolocation field, provided by the [Geolocation](https://drupal.org/project/geolocation) module, and an integer field (the radius from the user's location which the user enters).

My idea is to use the geodata from every new node that gets created (I store it in WKT format), the users' location and radius from the flag and send off notifications after calculating proximity. Ideally with Rules, but it hasn't worked so far (Rules doesn't seem to recognize flag fields).